# Should I post a duplicate question when the current answers do not resolve my problem?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

There are already multiple similar questions with useful and approved answers.  These answers helped the OPs.  I have tried/checked everything suggested in those answers, but still have the same apparent "symptoms."

Should I do something inside the old question?

Should I post a similar/duplicate question stating all the attempts I have made using the information from the old answers?

Is there another option to get help on SO?

Comment: It is a duplicate.  I did actively search and not find that question before I posted.  @gunr2171 Thank you for your answer and link to the other question.

Comment: You can't delete this post because my answer has at least 1 upvote. So we just have to convince 4 other people to close your question.

Answer (score 5):

The close text when a question is a duplicate reads:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.

So, if you have a similar question, and you can *prove* that it is different than possible duplicates, then it's fine to ask your question.

I would suggest linking to those other questions and explaining how they did not solve your problem.

Comment: Linking and explaining is a better way to ask a duplicate

Comment: @HipHopDroid, I thought that's what I said. Are you saying I said something wrong?

Comment: No I am supporting you. And I know that is not supposed to be written in comments but anyway